# _tkinter.TclError:unknown option "23" Code works with few object, but not with many

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

To start off I am super new at using Tkinter,

The problem I am having is that my code works if I have only one of the object type. It will interact correctly if it is the only one of that tag type. So if I have one 'boat' and 100 'shells' each time it executes, it does so correctly.

The code detects if there is collision between two objects and then changes the currently selected item's color to a random. So as long as there is only one tag type currently it will work correctly. So if I click and drag the 'boat' into a 'shell' it will switch it's color. Then if I take 1 of the 100 'shell's and do the same I get this error.

I do not understand why it works correctly when there is only one object of a given type and to interacts a infinite amount of other objects but when there is more than one of a tag type it fails.

It correctly selects the id number for the selected object so I am just lost right now and appreciate any help.

Follows is the error I receive and the code I am using. It is just the vital parts needed to preform the needed task. The collision code is the same as in the code though.

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:/Charles Engen/PycharmProjects/Battleship/BattleShipGUI.py", line 112, in on_token_motion
    self.collision_detection(event)
  File "H:/Charles Engen/PycharmProjects/Battleship/BattleShipGUI.py", line 85, in collision_detection
    self.canvas.itemconfig(current_token, outline=_random_color())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2385, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1259, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "22"
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 680

def _random_color():
    '''Creates a random color sequence when called'''
    random_color = ("#"+("%06x" % randint(0, 16777215)))
    return random_color

class Board(tk.Tk):
    '''Creates a Board Class'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.menu_item = tk.Menu(self)
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_item, tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='New', command=self.new_game)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.quit)

        self.config(menu=self.file_menu)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # adds variable that keeps track of location
        self._token_location_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}


    def _create_object(self, coord, fcolor, color, token_name):
        '''Creates an object with a tag, each object is assigned the ability to be clicked and dragged'''
        (x, y) = coord
        if token_name == 'boat':
            points = [10+x, 10+y, 20+x, 20+y, 110+x, 20+y, 120+x, 10+y, 80+x,
                      10+y, 80+x, 0+y, 60+x, 0+y, 60+x, 10+y]
            self.canvas.create_polygon(points, outline=fcolor, fill=color, width=3, tag=token_name)
        elif token_name == 'shell':
            self.canvas.create_oval(0+x, 0+y, 10+x, 10+y, outline=fcolor, fill=color, width=3, tag=token_name)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(token_name, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_token_button_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(token_name, '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_token_button_press)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(token_name, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_token_motion)

    def collision_detection(self, event):
        '''This function tracks any collision between the boat and shell objects'''
        # I will upgrade this to take any object collision
        token = self.canvas.gettags('current')[0]
        current_token = self.canvas.find_withtag(token)

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(token)
        overlap = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)

        for item in current_token:
            for over in overlap:
                if over != item:
                    # Changes the color of the object that is colliding.
                    self.canvas.itemconfig(current_token, outline=_random_color())

    # The following three functions are required to just move the tokens
    def on_token_button_press(self, event):
        '''Adds ability to pick up tokens'''
        # Stores token item's location data
        self._token_location_data['item'] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._token_location_data['x'] = event.x
        self._token_location_data['y'] = event.y

    def on_token_button_release(self, event):
        '''Adds ability to drop token'''
        # Resets the drag
        self._token_location_data['item'] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        self._token_location_data['x'] = event.x
        self._token_location_data['y'] = event.y

    def on_token_motion(self, event):
        '''Adds ability to keep track of location of tokens as you drag them'''
        # Computes how much the object has moved
        delta_x = event.x - self._token_location_data['x']
        delta_y = event.y - self._token_location_data['y']
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._token_location_data['item'], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._token_location_data['x'] = event.x
        self._token_location_data['y'] = event.y
        # Detects collision between objects
        self.collision_detection(event)

    def new_game(self):
        '''Creates new game by deleting the current canvas and creating new objects'''
        # Deletes current canvas
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        # runs the create board mechanism
        self._generate_board()
        # adds code to create a shell and boat on the screen from the appropriate function
        for i in range(1):
            self._create_object((410, 15*i), _random_color(), _random_color(), 'boat')
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(10):
                self._create_object((590+(i*10), 15*j), _random_color(), _random_color(), 'shell')

def main():
    app = Board()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: can you please show the full error message. It will contain the line number of the code that is giving the error.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging at all? Have you examined what `current_token` and `overlap` are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the code, I removed the call to the non-existent `._generate_board`.  After this, I get the same error but with unknown option '3'.

The exception is caused by passing to `self.canvas.itemconfig` a tuple of ids, which you misleadingly call `current_token`, instead of a tag or id. A singleton is tolerated because of the `_flatten` call, but anything more becomes an error.  I am rather sure that it is not a coincidence that '3' is the second member of the shell tuple.  Passing `token` instead stops the exception.  Also, there should be a break after `itemconfig` is called the first time.

With this, however, the shells are treated as a group, and the bounding box incloses all shells and `overlap` includes all shells.  This is why moving a single shell away from the others is seen as a collision.  At this point, all shells are randomized to a single new color if one is moved.  To fix this, token should be set to the single item set in `on_token_button_press`, instead of a tag group.  This implements your todo note.  Here is the result.

```
def collision_detection(self, event):
    '''Detect collision between selected object and others.'''
    token = self._token_location_data['item']
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(token)
    overlap = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    for over in overlap:
        if over != token:
            # Changes the color of the object that is colliding.
            self.canvas.itemconfig(token, outline=_random_color())
            break
```

A minor problem is that you do the tag binds for 'shell' for each shell (in `_create_object`.  Instead, put the tag binds in `new` so they are done once.

```
for tag in 'boat', 'shell':
    self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_token_button_press)
    self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_token_button_press)
    self.canvas.tag_bind(tag, '<B1-Motion>', self.on_token_motion)
```

Comment: Did not know you could do it in that order, I was fighting with it all night so I was just having problems. I tried several different ways trying to force my solution and forgot you can just try a different angle of attack. Also I never though about assigning the keys after item creation and frankly I did not know you could do it like that. That you mention it was returning a tuple confirms the results I was getting while trying to debug it. I just did not have the experience necessary to understand it was an issue. So again I appreciate you taking the time to teach me.

Comment: Some of the stuff in collision_detection is new for me too.  The key step in debugging was to add `print(token, current_token, (x1, y1, x2, y2), overlap)` just before the loop, then run and move both the boat and a shell.  This made it clear that current_token was a tuple of either 1 (no error) or 40 ids (error), and that bbox('shell') included all the shells.  I could also see the difference when changing token to the saved id instead of a tag.